# Google Drive API and EXIF data

Tags: google-drive-api, exif

I am NOT a JavaScript developer, but need to find out if what I want to do is even possible.  I want to modify EXIF data of images stored in Google drive.  Can I use the drive API and Javascript to do that?  Are there other solutions?

Comment: From the docs it would appear that you can change a limited set of EXIF data, date taken etc. - but you can't view or change any EXIF field.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Picasa API. It's documented here https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol

NB. I haven't used it to update exif myself, but the docs suggest that the full exif schema is exposed.